# Magento new product widget image resize

Tags: magento, widget, grid, product

I'm running magento with a custom template. I have been trying for the past week to enlarge the image size of the new product widget (whether grid or list) to be 232px width and 280px length. I have successfully located the new_grid.phtml and new_list.phtml files at
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content.
I have also changed the images sizes from I think 85px width and 85px length to my desired 232px width by 280px length. Instead of enlarging the frame of the image and the image itself, the image seems to be enlarged but the frame remains the same at 85px 85px. So then you are only able to see a small portion of the image within the 85px by 85px image frame. 
The widget I'm talking about is the new product widget that you can insert from the CMS pages. I'm running magento community edition 1.7

Here's the code snippet for the new_grid.phtml. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<div class="widget-products">
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(232,280) ?>" width="232" height="280" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>)"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a css issue.

You seem to be correctly resizing the image here:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(232,280) ?>
```

To ensure that your new templates are getting processed the layout, you can enable template hints in system/configuration/developer tab.

Assuming you've got that right, its quite likely getting reset to 85px in the css.

from **widgets.css**

```
.widget-new-products .products-grid .product-image,
.widget-new-products .products-list .product-image { width:85px; height:85px; }
```

I highly recommend poking around in your favorite browser's inspection tool to figure out what rule exactly is overriding your server side change.

cheers

Comment: Oh God!!! You deserve a kiss from your favorite person! Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this like I did...

Mine was corrected by changing the grid list in new.phtml:

```html
<ul class="products-grid">
```

to:

```html
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use CSS For Image To set Height And Width TO your Desired Values, no need to update templates like

```
<Your Image class/id>{
width:50%;
max-width:100%;
}
```

2) Or You Can Use js as

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
    jQuery(".product-image img").attr({ width: "100%", height: "auto" });
});
```